# Tooltips are black text on black background

Tags: colors

My tooltips are black text on a black background, though it should be white text on a black background. Any ideas, suggestions are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me how do you access this window? (sorry I can't answer your particular question)

Comment: Which Ubuntu version you use? Did it happens on all programs or only Qt based?

Comment: Sergey - Sure. System / Preferences / Appearance, then "Customize", then "Colours".

Zetah - Oh, good question. It happens in Audacity. But other programs seem to be okay. I'm running Maverick.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, what fixed this was turning the colours to a light background and a dark foreground for the tooltips.